# Telling if someone has "liked" my Facebook page from my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fbml

I was hoping someone is a bit of a Facebook guru round here.

What I'm trying to do is show some different content to those who have liked our Facebook page to those that haven't using the fb:visible-to-connections FBML. I know it's possible to do this on Facebook Pages but I'm trying to work out if it's possible to do on our website.

Does anyone know?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note, the `fb:visible-to-connections` FBML is either deprecated or nearing deprecation. We cannot have FBML is page tabs no more, all should be iframes using the new signed_request parameter. With this `signed_request`, you can extract data that contains whether the user liked the current page or not.

As for your question, unfortunately there is no `signed_request` since you're outside of facebook. The only way to do your goal is:

1. Have a facebook login to identify the user
2. Query if the user has liked the page using:

   - [page.isFan](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/) using old REST API
   - [page_fan](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) table using FQL
3. [/me/likes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) call for the Graph API and look for the page